# Returning one row from inner join right table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I have three tables (TABLE_A, TABLE_B, TABLE_C) and I am joining them on C_MAIN_REF. TABLE_B has multiple entries and I need only one to be returned, doesn't matter which?

Any Ideas?

EDIT:

```
SELECT C.C_UNIT_CODE as BU,'EPLC' as PRODUCT, A.BENE_NM as CUSTOMER, A.C_MAIN_REF,
        A.C_TRX_REF, A.PRES_CCY, TO_CHAR(A.PRES_AMT) AS PRES_AMT, A.PRES_DT AS PRES_DATE,
        A.DOC_STAT, '' AS APPL_RESPONSE, A.SETTLE_STATUS as SETTLE_STATUS 
    FROM EPLC_EM_NEGO A
    INNER JOIN CPYT_SCHEDULE B
           ON a.C_MAIN_REF = b.C_MAIN_REF AND ROWNUM =1
    INNER JOIN EPLC_MASTER C
            ON a.C_MAIN_REF = c.C_MAIN_REF
    WHERE a.CLS_DRWG_FLG = 'NO' AND b.CPYT_UNPAID_FLAG = 'T'
```

Above is the current query I am using but the problem is that there are multiple entries in CPYT_SCHEDULE I don't want so the join shoul only include one row from CPYT_SCHEDULE table;

Currently above returns

```
BU   PRODUCT CUSTOMER               C_MAIN_REF   C_TRX_REF        PRES_CCY PRES_AMT  PRES_DATE DOC_STAT     SETTLE_STATUS
------------ ---------------------------------------------------- -------- --------- --------- ------------ -------------
GB01 EPLC    Finance Customer No. 5 XL000053GB01 XL000053GB01-01  USD      90000     24-AUG-12 COMPLIANT    Settle      
GB01 EPLC    Finance Customer No. 5 XL000053GB01 XL000053GB01-01  USD      90000     24-AUG-12 COMPLIANT    Settle       
GB01 EPLC    Finance Customer No. 5 XL000053GB01 XL000053GB01-01  USD      90000     24-AUG-12 COMPLIANT    Settle       
GB01 EPLC    Finance Customer No. 5 XL000053GB01 XL000053GB01-01  USD      90000     24-AUG-12 COMPLIANT    Settle
```

but the desired output is

```
BU   PRODUCT CUSTOMER               C_MAIN_REF   C_TRX_REF        PRES_CCY PRES_AMT  PRES_DATE DOC_STAT     SETTLE_STATUS
------------ ---------------------------------------------------- -------- --------- --------- ------------ -------------
GB01 EPLC    Finance Customer No. 5 XL000053GB01 XL000053GB01-01  USD      90000     24-AUG-12 COMPLIANT    Settle
```

Comment: can you show sample records with desired result?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: C_UNIT_CODE column is used from EPLC_MASTER. Those values are actually not duplicate but user doesn't all the field and with requested fields entries look duplicate.  Therefore, if only one row is returned from CPYT_SCHEDULE table that will be solved. I got the query from the prev. dev and if sub-select does the job I don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sub-select worked for me, thanks for all the answers and input.

```
SELECT C.C_UNIT_CODE as BU,'EPLC' as PRODUCT, A.BENE_NM as CUSTOMER, A.C_MAIN_REF, A.C_TRX_REF, A.PRES_CCY, TO_CHAR(A.PRES_AMT) AS PRES_AMT, A.PRES_DT AS PRES_DATE, A.DOC_STAT, '' AS APPL_RESPONSE, A.SETTLE_STATUS as SETTLE_STATUS
FROM E_EM_NEGO A, EPLC_MASTER C
WHERE a.CLS_DRWG_FLG = 'NO' AND a.C_MAIN_REF = c.C_MAIN_REF
     AND a.C_MAIN_REF = (
     SELECT C_MAIN_REF FROM CPYT_SCHEDULE B
     WHERE B.CPYT_UNPAID_FLAG = 'T' AND b.C_MAIN_REF = a.C_MAIN_REF AND rownum=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

something like this:

```
SELECT C.C_UNIT_CODE as BU,
       'EPLC' as PRODUCT, 
       A.BENE_NM as CUSTOMER, 
       A.C_MAIN_REF,
       A.C_TRX_REF, 
       A.PRES_CCY, 
       TO_CHAR(A.PRES_AMT) AS PRES_AMT, 
       A.PRES_DT AS PRES_DATE,
       A.DOC_STAT, 
       '' AS APPL_RESPONSE, 
       A.SETTLE_STATUS as SETTLE_STATUS 
FROM EPLC_EM_NEGO A
INNER JOIN (select cs.*, 
                   row_number() over (partition by C_MAIN_REF) as rn
            from CPYT_SCHEDULE cs) b 
       ON a.C_MAIN_REF = b.C_MAIN_REF AND b.rn = 1
INNER JOIN EPLC_MASTER C
        ON a.C_MAIN_REF = c.C_MAIN_REF
WHERE a.CLS_DRWG_FLG = 'NO' 
  AND b.CPYT_UNPAID_FLAG = 'T'
```

Comment: I tried to implement above code but get "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"" in sqldeveloper

Comment: @rojanu: sorry forgot some stuff (as I had to make up everything due to the missing table structure information).

Comment: Is it possible to do something like "INNER JOIN (SELECT cs.*, rownum as rn FROM EXIMSYS.CPYT_SCHEDULE cs WHERE cs.C_MAIN_REF = A.C_MAIN_REF ) B"? As what above returned is incorrect and I this thats because it returns the first entry in the whole table instead of the first of the "a.C_MAIN_REF = b.C_MAIN_REF" condition